# Jupyter fails to connect to kernel in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've switched to a MacOS a couple of days ago and I've been trying to setup my development environment to be the same as the one I had previously. Everything has been smooth but I can't get Jupyter to run inside of VS Code. To start, here are the paths of Python, iPython, and Jupyter (obtained using `where program_name`)

```
>>> where python3
/usr/bin/python3

>>> where iPython3
/Users/omarabdulla/Library/Python/3.7/bin/ipython3

>>> where Jupyter
/Users/omarabdulla/Library/Python/3.7/bin/jupyter
```

With that, I created a new Jupyter notebook and the following are the kernels I have available:
[Kernels available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK5PT.png). I chose the one in `/usr/bin/python3` because that's the path the `where` command indicated (but even other versions don't work too)

After I chose it I get a message saying `Connecting to IPython kernel: Connecting to kernel.` and then after a while it fails and I get a message saying `Unable to start session for kernel Python 3.7.3 64-bit. Select another kernel to launch with.`

Im not quite sure how to set it up to work. I've looked online but haven't really been able to find a solution to this issue. I would appreciate any input I could get on how I could solve this issue.

Comment: Did you install python3 using brew or is it the default python that came installed with MacOS

Comment: @Mohsinhasan Thanks for the reply! I didn't install Python3 myself. I'm using the one that came with the Mac. Should I try to install it using brew or using the installer from the python site?

Comment: Could you check in terminal, if ipython installation is correct. Run `python3` and `ipython` and check if they both point to same python version

Comment: @Mohsinhasan I've just verified that Python3, iPython, and iPython3 all work and without any issues. The iPython version is 7.18.1.

Comment: @OmarAbdulla You could try to check the version number of the module "traitlets", (pip list). One reason for this is that there are some issues with the updated traitlets5.0.0 version, and it is recommended to restore its version to 4.3.3. Refer to this link:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13701#issuecomment-684994934

Comment: @JillCheng Thank you so much that did fix the issue for me. However, I had to install it with `sudo`. Without it that didn't work. So the command became: `sudo python3 -m pip install 'traitlets==4.3.3' --force-reinstall`. Again, thank you so much for the help!